# Tell if a point is in an area of a square

Tags: circles, area

It's probably a basic question, but I would like to determine whether a point $(x, y)$ belongs to a square area defined by two points on a circle, that were created under some degree. Here I will draw an example:

[image: sample image]

Known data is as follows:

$\alpha$ - degree in which the line is drawn

$(x, y)$ - left top corner position of a square

$a$ - length of a square

I'm calculating the other data as follows (I can be wrong here):

$$r = a * {\sqrt 2} / 2$$

$$\text{circle Center Position X} = x + a/2$$

$$\text{circle Center Position Y}= y + a/2$$

$$\alpha = \alpha - 90$$

These two points on a circle calculated like this:

$p1x = \text{circle Center Position X} + radius * \cos(\alpha)$

$p1y = \text{circle Center Position Y} + radius * \sin(\alpha)$,

$p2x = \text{circle Center Position X} - radius * \cos(\alpha)$

$p2y = \text{circle Center Position Y}- radius * \sin(\alpha)$

Important to note is that Y axis values grow as we go down. X axis values grow as we go to the right as usual.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.  See also the **Edit-Images** section of the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the point is in the square (e.g. by checking directly with $x$ and $y$ coordinates). Next convert your $(x,y)$ value to polar coordinates (with angle between $0$ and $360$) and check its angle. If it lies between $\theta$ and $−(180−\theta)$ it will lie on one half of the line, otherwise it will lie on the other half. To get the angle, you can use the $\operatorname{atan2}$ function implemented in most programming languages.

Comment: oh man i need 15 reputation to upvote it says, thank You for answer. Feedback has been recorded it says though

Comment: It's fine, I just posted it so you can accept it and close the question (which doesn't require any reputation), as well as to clean up the comment section. I have no need for useless internet points :)